# About arangodb cluster performance improvement

Tags: arangodb, aql

I would like to ask some questions about the cluster network.First of all, I want to know why my cluster log can not be used? Is it because my cluster is not configured? My cluster starts as follows:
arangodb --starter.join 10.200.11.32,10.200.11.33,10.200.11.34,10.200.11.35
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Then there is a place in the collection I do not understand:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]
The percentage above said loaded into memory in the hundred?
There is when I import data, the index is entered into memory before entering the disk?
Index does not save to the disk has any impact on the query?
There is my custom _key will affect the query efficiency?
Does the number of collections and graphs affect the traversal of the graph?
There is a problem I do not understand, when I import the data, I immediately go to the query is very slow, and then wait for a night to check the same data, the efficiency has improved significantly, what is the reason?
There is the cluster start setting the number of threads, the cluster and server what is the use?
Start the cluster like me, there is no set or method to improve the performance of the cluster?
Does LAN affect the query?
All in all, what should I do to improve the efficiency of the query in the cluster, either from the configuration, set settings, or hardware, etc.
I have four nodes, the configuration is the same, as follows:
RAM:256G, core:40.
I know a lot of my problems, I sincerely hope that the great arangodb team can help me, thank you!

Comment: Hi, please provide the images you are referring to.
Please do not ask the same question at stackoverflow and our bug tracker (especially if it is a question and not a bug) - http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: Your questions have been answered here: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/4452